# How to databind property from view model to custom user control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a custom control that I created to test how binding works. It has a dependency property that I want to bind from another view and also I want it to update when binded property raises PropertyChanged using INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public string BindLabelText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(BindLabelTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BindLabelTextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty BindLabelTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("BindLabelText", typeof(string), typeof(BindingControl), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

In my control I bind dependency property like this:

```
<TextBlock 
    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Text="{Binding ElementName=TestControl, Path=BindLabelText,  FallbackValue=BindLabelText}" 
    FontSize="20"/>
```

And I use control like this:

```
<local:BindingControl BindLabelText="Static main window value" />
<local:BindingControl BindLabelText="{Binding HeaderLabel, FallbackValue=HeaderLabel}" />
<Button Content="Change MainWindow property" Command="{Binding ChangeMainTextCommand}"/>
```

TextBlock text value is set with a static value but it does not work when I try to bind it to a property. In both views I set DataContext to ViewModel in code behind:

`this.DataContext = new BindingControlViewModel();`

Edit:
Added my code to [github](https://github.com/aleksandraszagorskas/wpf-user-control-binding). Like I said in the comments I'm trying to bind property on MainWindowViewModel which is the DataContext for my parent View (MainWindow) to my User Control DP BindLabelText. User Control in addition to DP also has its own ViewModel. My goal is to have User Control that will update when bound property from MainWindowViewModel updates.

Comment: What is `TestControl`? Do you have binding errors in Output window?

Comment: TestControl is the name of my custom control. I get: BindingExpression path error: 'HeaderLabel' property not found on 'object' ''BindingControlViewModel' (HashCode=47044325)'. BindingExpression:Path=HeaderLabel; DataItem='BindingControlViewModel' (HashCode=47044325); target element is 'BindingControl' (Name='TestControl'); target property is 'BindLabelText' (type 'String'). HeaderLabel is on my MainWindowViewModel (view from which I use the control). BindingControlViewModel is the custom control ViewModel.

Comment: What is the data context of the XAML where you use the control? If it's not `BindingControlViewModel` you would need to create your binding : `<local:BindingControl BindLabelText="{Binding DataContext.HeaderLabel}` and set the data context at the top of the XAML `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm:YourViewModell}}"  `

Comment: The DataContext where I use the control is MainWindowViewModel I want to bind the property of this ViewModel to my custom control BindLabelText DP.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested, with setting the data context of the main view to MainWindowViewModel? so in `MainWindow.cs` you would have `DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()`; and in the code-behind of your control keep it as `DataContext = new BindingControlViewModel()`. In the xaml set the data context at the top `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm:YourViewModell}}"` and the binding on the control to `{Binding DataContext.HeaderLabel}`

Comment: What is BindingControlViewModel? It would be much easier to help without asking one question after another. See [mcve]. From what I can guess - you are making custom control, means you should not set its `DataContext` explicitly, nor it needs own view model.

Comment: @VM I have tried setting the data context `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}}"` in the Control xaml and binded control like `{Binding DataContext.HeaderLabel}`. But now I get extra binding errors: BindingExpression path error: 'DataContext' property not found on 'object' ''BindingControlViewModel'. Also I have added my code to github so the problem could be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by setting my control DataContext to grid like `MyGrid.DataContext = new BindingControlViewModel();` instead of setting it on the control itself like `this.DataContext = new BindingControlViewModel();`.